# Visit in Schengen region but from different country

Tags: schengen-visas, multiple-entry

I am an Indian Citizen and I have been issued Schengen visa by The Netherlands embassy in New Delhi. This is a 'Type C' multiple entry visa, applied by my project for Business purpose.

I could never travel from that project and my visa is not stamped yet. My visa is still valid till Sept'19. Meanwhile, I came to the UK for another project.  Now I am looking to Visit Italy from the UK for tourism and had no plans to visit The Netherlands anytime soon. So my questions are:

1. Can I directly enter Italy without entering The Netherlands?
2. Since my previous project never issued any tickets so I do not have any 
   itinerary. So If I book hotels and traveling tickets for Italy, it would be 
   my original Itenary. Do I fulfill the requirements?

Comment: Since you've never used the issued visa for the purpose it was issued for, and the intention you have now (tourism) is different, the safest thing to do would be not to try using the issued visa, but apply for a new visa and note in the application that you have one that was never used because things changed.

Comment: But why the Italian embassy will issue the new visa, when they will see that I already have a valid visa but from a different country? Will they cancel my previous visa and issue the new one?